# Angular 6: Section "app" in the new angular.json format

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular-cli-v6

In Angular 6, we can specify different applications in the app section of angular-cli.json, as we can see on ["Stories Multiples Apps"](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-multiple-apps).

How can we implement this functionality in the new format of angular.json? Maybe in the projects section? Please, help me with an example.

Here there is a link to the [new format specification.](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/angular-workspace)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some test and I can say that I understand this funcionality, I'm writing here for any that have the same question.

In the past funcionality, it can be differents apps for a single project. If you want to have more apps, you can generate them with the command:

```
ng generate application app-name
```

Then, you can build it with:

```
ng build app-name
```

or just serve it with:

```
ng serve app-name
```

In my development, I use it to have an app for a client and another for admin purposes.